# This Apple ID cannot be used to make purchases

Tags: apple-id, mdm, volume-purchase-program, apple-business

I just wiped my iPad using Apple Configurator 2, and linked it to my MDM which is ManageEngine. I am enrolled in ABM and have purchases enough licences of the app I want to install. I can see the apps in the App Catalog, but they are stuck on "Installing". I constantly get a pop-up saying "This Apple ID cannot be used to make purchases."

I have tried using the admin Apple ID instead of a simple employee one, but it does not seem to solve the issue. Is there a change I need to apply to the ManageEngine Profile in order to make it work?

Thanks a lot!